# Average Value - Graphs

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

[image]

long method: Determine an equation for each and solve using average value formula

alternative methods?

How could you prove the average value to be C over an interval [a,b] if you are given a graph.... looking for most efficient/unique methods.

Comment: In general you would integrate the function (to find the area below the curve) and divide by the length of the interval ($b-a=6$ here) but I think what is expected here is just to use a bit of guesswork: graph A clearly has an average $>2$, whereas by computing the area of triangles you can find that the average of C and D are 2 and 4 respectively.
To show that B has $>2$, just draw the triangle {(0,0),(6,0),(3,4)} : it is contained in the area of the curve and has area =2

Answer (score 1):

Your equation for this question is:

$$\frac{1}{6}*\int_0^6 h(x) = 2$$

Therefore,

$$\int_0^6 h(x) = 12$$

For answers $c$ and $d$ you can use the area of a triangle,

If you try answer choice $c$,

We get that:

$$A = \frac{1}{2}*4.5*6 - \frac{1}{2}*1.5*(-2) = 12$$

Therefore our answer is C.

Answer (score 0):

Graph A:
The part for $x\in[0,2)$ compensates with the part for $x\in (2,4]$, giving an average of 2 over the interval $[0,4]$. But the part for $x\in(4,6]$ is above the line $y=2$. So A is not good.

GraphB:
Define a new function $g$ whose graph is composed of one straight line between $(0,0)$ and $(3,4)$ and the other straight line between $(3,4)$ and $(6,0)$. Similarly as in case A, we can see average of the function $g$ is equal to 2. But the graph of $f$ is always above $g$. So B is not good.

Similarly, we find average in graph C is 2 and average in Graph D is 4